# Delivering a Get when the wife is far away

Tags: halacha, divorce, shlichus-agency

During a divorce proceeding, should the husband's wife ideally be given the Gett in person, even if she lives ~3000 miles away?  (The divorce is consented by both parties and they are relatively amicable.)

Should great effort be made to do the Gett in person in this case?  Or is it perfectly acceptable to [appoint a schliach to deliver the Gett](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.32a.2?lang=bi)?  And in that case, is there something spiritually that one would be missing out on?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for the question! If this is a practical issue, make sure to [ask your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi) rather than rely on anything from this site. Also, if you've found anything relevant in your research, please go ahead and add your sources to the question.

Comment: There is indeed a possibility for a woman to receive a get by shaliach and for a man to give a get by shaliach, שליח קבלה ושליח הולכה. masechet Gittin treats the issues of get by shaliach widely

Comment: The overall principle here, in theory, is "there is more of a mitzvah to do it one's self than by appointing a proxy." I would ask the particular Beis Din handling this Gett how much they prefer that it be in-person. "Spiritually missing out on" -- the mitzvah to *give* the Gett is the man's, so it's the same for the woman regardless. Some people find the process of severing ties face-to-face cathartic, others would rather not; but that's a practical psychological question and not a "spiritual" one per se. Short answer -- ask whichever rabbis are handling this (or you might ask to).

Answer (score 4):

There is no question that it is perfectly acceptable to appoint a *shaliach* (messenger ) to deliver the divorce document (*get*). The Rambam (Mishne Torah Gerushin [chapter 6](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/957711/jewish/Gerushin-Chapter-Six.htm)) writes

> (6:3) **A husband may [...] appoint an agent to deliver a get to his
>   wife.** Such an agent is referred to as a delivery agent (sh'liach
>   holachah). (6:13) Until the get is given to the woman, the status of
>   the divorce is in doubt. **Once it reaches her possession, the divorce
>   is definitely binding.**

Now the question is whether to write a *get* is a *mitsva*. I originally thought it was (based on the Rambam's [intro to Sefer Gerushin](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/957706/jewish/Gerushin-Chapter-One.htm)). When I discussed your question with R Binyamin Tabady, he mentioned the Maharsha writes that it is only a *mitsva* if the woman behaved improperly (e.g., relations with others), otherwise writing a *get* is permitted but is in no way a *mitsva*.

If it is a *mitsva*, we can build on the gemara in [Kiddushin 41a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.41a.4?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) which writes

> it is more fitting that the mitzva be performed by the man himself
>   than by means of his agent.

as well as the gemara in [Baba Kama 9b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.9b.2?lang=bi) which writes that

> what Rabbi Zeira said is that for the embellishment of the performance
>   of a mitzva, e.g., to purchase a more beautiful item used in the
>   performance of a mitzva, one should spend up to one-third more than
>   the cost of the standard item used to perform the mitzva.

to suggest that there is a *hiddur mitsva* (beautification of the *mitsva*) to do it in person.

But if the divorce is due to personal preferences, e.g., lack of fit between the spouses, then these *gemarot* don't apply and there is no benefit to giving the *get* in person.

In all cases, a rabbi who knows the couple should be approached to balance the above sources with his knowledge of the specifics of the situation and help come to a practical decision.

Comment: Do these concepts really apply to delivering a bill of divorce personally? The Gemara says מצוה בו יותר מבשלוחו about betrothal, and applying hiddur to delivering a bill of divorce seems a little strange to me

Comment: (From what I understood from being present at a Gett given in the Eida Chareidis in Jslm, all Gittin are given via Shaliach, even if both parties are in the same room. Not sure that's true.)

Comment: @ba I wondered as well and discussed the question further - then edited my answer. Thanks for the push

Comment: This doesn't address any of the practical aspects of this. It can be a much bigger pain to arrange a get via messenger even if it works.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I've seen the husband place it directly in her hand.

Comment: @DoubleAA I hear you. From my limited experience speaking with people who went through this, the *beit din* which writes the get would arrange for the delivery. They do this frequently so have all the arrangements in place

Comment: @Danny, I heard that a get is normally given by sheliach to avoid either party getting upset or overly emotional at the time of giving it over and prolonging the procedure. The OP asks specificly when it is consented by both parties.

Comment: Any idea where this מהרש"א is? This is useful info. Shkoach for a nice answer (again).

Comment: @DannySchoemann I believe Gitin 90 but am traveling and couldn’t check